# Save Boolean state while restarting the application

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 6 boolean variables which I have initialized as false. There are 6 different imageviews which are associated with these 6 boolean false variables. When the user clicks any of these image, there respective boolean variable is switched to true and when the user again clicks the same image, it will turn to false like on and off. After being satisfied with the selected options, the user can click the done button and the data will be save in the firebase accordingly to whether which options are true and which are `false`.

My problem is that whenever the application is restarted, all boolean variables are again initialized to false, I understand the fact that, the application restarts for OnCreate class due to which the variables are again false. How can I write a certain code which can save the state of these variables even after application restarts?

Below is my Code:

```
    boolean checkcar = false, checkPickUp = false, checkTruck = false, checkCycle = false, checkBike = false, checkMen = false;
  private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private String currentUserID;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    myTransport = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_transport, container, false);
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    currentUserID = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    carImage = myTransport.findViewById(R.id.carTransport);
    pickUpImage = myTransport.findViewById(R.id.pickUpTransport);
    truckImage = myTransport.findViewById(R.id.truckTransport);
    cycleImage = myTransport.findViewById(R.id.cyclerTransport);
    bikeImage = myTransport.findViewById(R.id.bikeTransport);
    menImage = myTransport.findViewById(R.id.menTransport);
    done = myTransport.findViewById(R.id.selectUserTransportBtn);
    transport = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserProfileDetails").child(currentUserID).child("Transport");



    MarkUserRegisteredTransport();


    carImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

    if (!checkcar) {
        carImage.setColorFilter(carImage.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.TransportAfterClicked), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        checkcar = true;
    } else {
        carImage.setColorFilter(carImage.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        checkcar = false;
    }
        }
    });


    pickUpImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             if (!checkPickUp) {
        pickUpImage.setColorFilter(pickUpImage.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.TransportAfterClicked), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        checkPickUp = true;
    } else {
        pickUpImage.setColorFilter(pickUpImage.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        checkPickUp = false;
    }
        }
    });

    truckImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             if (!checkTruck) {
        truckImage.setColorFilter(truckImage.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.TransportAfterClicked), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        checkTruck = true;
    } else {
        truckImage.setColorFilter(truckImage.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        checkTruck = false;
    }
        }
    });

    cycleImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!checkCycle) {
        cycleImage.setColorFilter(cycleImage.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.TransportAfterClicked), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        checkCycle = true;
    } else {
        cycleImage.setColorFilter(cycleImage.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        checkCycle = false;
    }
        }
    });

    bikeImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


    menImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!checkMen) {
        menImage.setColorFilter(menImage.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.TransportAfterClicked), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        checkMen = true;
    } else {
        menImage.setColorFilter(menImage.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        checkMen = false;
    }

        }
    });
```

here is when user can click done and the information is updated in the firebase with true or false with their res

```
    done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                   HashMap userTransport = new HashMap();
    userTransport.put("check Car", checkcar);
    userTransport.put("check PickUp", checkPickUp);
    userTransport.put("check Truck", checkTruck);
    userTransport.put("check Cycle", checkCycle);
    userTransport.put("check bike", checkBike);
    userTransport.put("check Men", checkMen);

    transport.updateChildren(userTransport).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Transportation information updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error Occured: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
        }
    });
    return myTransport;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment:

> well i needed the data to be stored even after the user deletes the application just like instagram and facebook

I would like to tell you that either `SharedPreferences` nor `Bundle` won't help in this case. Both tehniques when used, do not persist across application uninstalls. If you reinstall the app, your `SharedPreferences` or your `Bundle` will be empty and you will not be able to use any data at all.

To solve this, I recommend you add that data to database and everytime the user wants to update his preferences, change the data in database accordingly. So create six new properties of type boolean under your `transport` object and set/update them accordingly with user's choice.

Comment: Hi joe! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Done...Sorry i am new to stack overflow. so getting familiar with things..thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

You can use onSaveInstanceState to save the boolean values, and fetch the values in onCreate or onRestoreInstanceState.

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("boolean1", booleanValue1);
    outState.putString("boolean2", booleanValue2); //and so on

}
```

```java
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    if(savedInstanceState!=null){
       if(getString("boolean1") != null){
        booleanValue1 = savedInstanceState.getString("boolean1");
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: will this code work when the application is completely destroyed and reopened from scratch and when multiple users can run the application and select there boolean options???

Comment: @joewalker you can always save the values in a text file and retrieve those values when you need.

Comment: You can use sharedpreference to store the boolean values, it will not be destroyed untill the apps data is cleared or uninstalled.

Answer (score -1):

Use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences), if the application is killed the values saved will not be deleted or reset.

```
PreferenceManager mManager = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

//example methods

public static boolean getBool(String resName, boolean defValue) {
        return mManager.getBoolean(resName, defValue);
    }

public static void setBool(String resName, boolean value) {
    mManager.edit()
            .putBoolean(resName, value)
            .apply();
}
```

PS: Well, if you uninstall the app or delete the app data (in "Settings", for example) datas will be destroyed

Comment: well i needed the data to be stored even after the user deletes the application just like instagram and facebook where the account data is saved... i think i should retrieve data from firebase when the user visits the acitivity, In this way his latest preserved data will always be retrieved in the oncreate and assign them to the boolean varibales

Comment: @joewalker ok, i suggest to you to edit your question adding the behaviour that you need (retrieve datas after re-installing the app, etcc). You can follow two ways: store datas on a remote database and then retrive it by a request, or you can create a physical backup on the storage and the reload it